# receiving large integers from Arduino over Bluetooth + Android + appinventor

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino

I am developing a simple RPM sensing with arduino and appinventor. I am facing a problem which Android do not receives integer values greater than 255 or a lot of garbage from Arduino BT.

The logic over arduino already works great. It shows correctly RPM on 16x2 LCD with nice precision.
I also want to send RPM over bluetooth to android with appinventor interface. It works but only shows values 255 maximum. Even when LCD shows 1000+ RPM, on android always shows between 0 and 255.

I've tried to use typecasting (to char, and print it as text without success). Also changed received bytes on appinventor (from 1 to 4 bytes)

Arduino's code:

```
// include libraries
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

const int resolution = 500;
// initialize the library with the numbers of the interface pins
LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);

//hardware global constants;
const int inputPin = 7;
const int ledPin = 13;
//const int bluetoothTx = 9;
//const int bluetoothRx = 8;

//logical variables
int inputState = 0;
int lastPinState;
int counter = 0;
int timeI = 0;
int timeF = 0;
int revolutions;
int cilinderRatio = 2;
int rpm = 0;
char * data = 0;
//---------------------------------------
//BLUETOOTH RESERVED

void setup() {
  //set up input Pin and integrated led (pin13)
  pinMode(inputPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  // set up the LCD's number of columns and rows: 
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  // Print a message to the LCD.
  lcd.print("RPM:");
  //Setup Bluetooth Serial Connection to Android
  //pinMode(bluetoothTx, OUTPUT);
  //pinMode(bluetoothRx, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() {
  rpm = 0;
  revolutions = 0;
  counter = 0;
  // set the cursor to column 0, line 1
  // (note: line 1 is the second row, since counting begins with 0):
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  timeI = millis(); //get current running time
  do{
    //get current state
    inputState = digitalRead(inputPin);
    //if a pulse occurs, continues
    if(inputState == HIGH) {
    //if last state is not equal to last state, count it increasing 1 
    if(lastPinState != inputState)
    {
      counter += 1;
    }
  } 
  lastPinState = inputState; // takes current input State as last state
  timeF = millis(); //get final execution time
 }while((timeF - timeI) < resolution); //Repeat until reach resolution sample
 //lcd.print(counter); //Print how much pulses was counted
 // Revolutions is how much resolutions occured in one minute
 //since resolution is a seconds fraction, 1000mS * 60S must be
 //considered for RPMs 
 revolutions = counter * (60000 / resolution);
 //lcd.print(revolutions); //Print how much turns was counted, in fact
 //Revolutions divided by cilinderRatio is equal to RPM
 rpm = revolutions / cilinderRatio;
 rpm = rpm / 2;
 lcd.print(rpm); //Print Revolutions per minute
 lcd.print("                ");
 Serial.write(rpm);
 rpm = 0;
 counter = 0;
 digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
}
```

P.S.: I've changed received bytes to 2 to manage better integers large than 255. However, it shows a lot of garbage easily over 255.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by separating each byte.

first, was defined a data array size of 2 byte type:

```
byte data[2];
```

then following expression put each byte of rpm in a single byte:

```
data[0] = (byte) rpm; //typecast of rpm integer to byte
data[0] = ((byte) rpm >> 8); //typecast and 8-bit shift
```

Comment: I think there is typo in your answer the second line should be data[1] = ((byte)rpm >> 8);

Answer (score 0):

As per Arduino doc on Serial write http://arduino.cc/en/Serial/Write. The Serial.Write sends one byte at a time or series of bytes. Hence you will need to convert your integer RPM to string of number 
using itoa or something like it.

You can also use Serial.print() instead to directly send integer as digits.

Comment: The uses of itoa doesn`t work very well with Crystal Display library.